# How can I find the areal velocity of a body, moving under a central force, in Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, coordinate-systems

My textbook tells me that the areal velocity of a body under central force is expressed by $\vec A$ = $r^2$$\dot\theta$$\hat k$. How can I express this in Cartesian coordinates, since the above expressesion is for polar coordinates? I tried by substituting $r$ = $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? You have to substitute for $\theta$ also : $(x,y) \to (r,\theta)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably $\hat{k}$ is a unit vector orthogonal to the $x,y$ plane? If the areal velocity is defined as [the rate at which area is swept out by a particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areal_velocity), the correct expression is 
$$ \vec{A} = \frac{1}{2} r^2 \dot{\theta} \hat k$$
with $r, \theta$ being the usual polar coordinates (that 1/2 comes from the area of the infinitesimal triangle being swept out). Using the definitions
$$ \begin{align}
     r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \\
     \tan \theta = y / x
\end{align} $$
you'll find $\dot{\theta} = (x\dot y - y\dot x)/ (x^2 + y^2)$, and therefore
$$ \vec{A} = \frac{1}{2} (x\dot y - y\dot x) \hat k $$
up to a possible minus sign in the definition of $\hat k$.

If this looks like a cross product, that's because [it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areal_velocity) :)